# restoring Postgres database: pg_restore -vs- just using psql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am dumping my Postgres database using [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html) (in plain-text format) and then restore it simply by using [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html) (with the `-f` option).

Which begs the question: am I missing anything by not using [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgrestore.html) which seems like a specialized restore tool (compared to the generic `psql`)?

I can control options like disabling of triggers and such by using `pg_dump` parameters. What, then, is `pg_restore` used for? non-plain-text dump formats ?

Comment: [From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html): "*pg_restore is a utility for restoring a PostgreSQL database from an archive created by pg_dump in one of the **non-plain-text formats***"

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you created an SQL-format dump, all you *can* use is `psql`.

If you created a custom-format (`pg_dump -Fc`) or directory-format (`pg_dump -Fd`) dump, you can and must use `pg_restore`.

Custom and directory format dumps offer a lot of advantages over plain SQL script dumps, and I use them exclusively. You can selectively restore only some tables/schema, can choose whether to include only schema, only data, or both at restore time, etc. Lots of the options you have to specify at `pg_dump` time with SQL-format dumps can be chosen at *restore-time* if you use a custom-format dump and `pg_restore`.

If it weren't for backward compatibility I'm sure the default for `pg_dump` would be `-Fc` (custom) format.

You can't convert an SQL-format dump into custom-format or directory-format without restoring it to a PostgreSQL database and then dumping the restored DB.

Comment: Is it also possible to batch rename functions and do data manipulation like you could in a sql file with a good regexp?

Comment: No, but you can `pg_restore` without a `dbname` argument to turn it *into* a SQL-format dump if you need one. You cannot do the reverse.

Comment: @CraigRinger is there any speed difference using psql vs using pg_dump for restore?

Comment: @NikunjSardhara Not usually, but `pg_restore` supports parallel restore, and if you use that it'll be a LOT faster.